# Any way to move id to front of class in PhpStorm

Tags: html, phpstorm, reformatting

This is the code when I typed:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="billing-address-default" checked>
```

Any method can I reformat the code to make the id move in front of class?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="billing-address-default" class="form-check-input" checked>
```

Answer (score 1):

Attributes order can be configured in **Settings | Editor | Code Style -> HTML -> Arrangement**: by default, attributes are sorted in alphabetical order, but you can delete the default rule and add your own, defining a custom order.

To get the attributes re-arranged, please use **Code | Rearrange Code** action, or make sure that **Rearrange Code** is enabled in **Reformat File** dialog to make this work on reformatting the file

[image]

Note that you can use **Code | Show Reformat file** dialog to edit the preferences